# PHP: Class_A calls Class_B calls Class_C — How to pass variable from A to C?

Tags: php, oop

I have a chain of classes. Class_A instantiates Class_B which instantiates Class_C. (In reality, Class_A instantiates three classes, and each of those classes instantiate a few. So it's more of a tree of classes that branch out from Class_A).

Class_A holds a variable that all of those final classes (the ones called by Class_B) all need.

How best to pass the variable down? Right now I pass it as an argument to Class_B, and then Class_B passes it along again as an argument to Class_C. But this seems redundant.

```
class Class_A {

   function __construct(){

       $m = value;

       $n = new Class_B($m);

   }
}

class Class_B {

    function __construct($m){

        $o = new Class_C($m);

    }

}

class Class_C {

    function __construct($m){

         $this->m = $m;

         $this->do_something();

    }

    public function do_something(){

         return $this->m;

    }

}
```

Should Class_A set a global variable that all its descendants in the branch can inherit?

Should all my subclasses be extending the classes that instantiate them just to get access to this variable?

Comment: the "best" way should be to don't break demeter's law. you may want refactor your classes keeping in mind the single responsibility principle

Comment: Reviewing common design patterns would help, particularly factory and/or decorator: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_design_pattern